# Scheduled Distribution of Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, email, scheduled

Is this possible - 
And if so, would it be possible to be sent as:

- link?
- attachment?

and to what kind of recipient list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use apex and use `page.getContent()` method to generate PDF content from visualforce page and send it as attachment in email. Check out below link,

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/16/create-and-email-a-pdf-with-salesforce-com/

Comment: thanks. That page has some help but doesn't address scheduling...

Comment: you can use the same code in a batch class and schedule the batch class to run at the time you like. This batch class will send email to recipient list.